# calculate the limit for $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + ......}}}}$

Tags: nested-radicals

What I got right now is: 
$a_0 = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$, $a_1 = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + a_0}}$, and $a_n = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + a_{n-1}}}$. I can say $a = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2 + a}}$, right? If yes, how to show that $a = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2 + a}}$?

Comment: Unravel it by first squaring a, subtracting 1, squaring again, subtracting 2.  Then you have a on the right and you can solve the polynomial..

Comment: you can say $a=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+a}}$ if the limit of $a_n$ exists, so you only need to show the limit exists somehow. Then take the limit as $n\to\infty$ on both sides to get the equality

Comment: that is the part I don't know... how to show that limit exists...

Comment: Would increasing and bounded above help?

Comment: @VincentZheng compare it to sqrt(2+sqrt2+(...

Comment: @Alephnull What for?

Comment: @Did boundedness

Comment: @Alephnull Sorry but I do not get the argument. One will have, anyway, to show that "sqrt(2+sqrt(2+sqrt...", whatever that means, is bounded -- and the argument to do that is not simpler than to solve the case the OP asks about.

Comment: @Did it is wel known.

Comment: @Alephnull Yeah, but the value of this argument is zero since the exercise the OP asks is also well known...

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is bounded above by $2$: certainly $a_0<2$ since $\sqrt{2}<3$

Once you know $a_{n-1}<2$, $a_n<\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+2}}=\sqrt{3}<2$

increasing: $a_1>a_0$ clearly, and use induction again

So bdd above, incerasing -> convergent

Answer (score 1):

Consider for $x\geq 0$ the map
$$ f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+x}}.$$ The derivative of the map is
$$ 0\leq f'(x)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+x}}\; \sqrt{2+x}}\leq \frac{1}{4}$$
By the MVT $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \frac{1}{4}|x-y|$ is a Lipschitz contraction of ${\Bbb R}_+$ which is a complete metric space. Whence the sequence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, $a_0=0$ converges to a unique fixed point of $f$.